# Show/hide modal in code from different Component, Angular 4 Typescript Project,

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I started working on my App for university and got some problem when trying to open Bootstrap modal in code from different component.
I have no problems opening a component in code from the same component. I use jquery and it works just fine:

```
hideLoginModal(){
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
}
```

The modal needs to pop up and hide when you click on Navigation Bar button in NavigationComponent. 
The problem is that "LoginModal" and all functions conntected to logging in should be in the AccountComponent and right now I've got them stuck in NavigationComponent.

So I tried to move my "LoginModal" html and hideLoginModal() function + other login fuctions to AccountComponent/AccountService and in NavigationComponent when clicking on "Login" button I just call accountService.openModal() or accountService.hideModal().

I thought it should work but the problem is it appears $('#myModal') in AccountComponent returns null when called like that.

So I figured it's probably because when you're clicking on "Login" button in NavigationComponent, the htmls of AccountComponent do not exist/are not initialized because you never earlier entered this page or routed to it before logging in (because you can't, you can see AccountComponent view only after you log in)? 
Am I understanding it correctly or is the reason something else?
Is there any workaround?

It's very possible I'm very wrong about it and do not understand the problem correctly. Just started learning typescript and angular.
Can anyone help?

Comment: You need a way to have the components communicate with each other. Are they siblings components? Are they Parent-Child components? You need to have those questions answered then you can decide what strategy to bridge them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ngBootstrap.
I have resolved it as below.
This is my Modal

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal" role="dialog" [ngbCollapse]="showModal">
""
""
""
</div>
```

In your ts file, you have to declare a variable

```
showModal = true;
```

Suppose, I want to toggle the modal on click of button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" (click) = "toggleModal()">YES</button>
```

Now in your ts file create a function

```
toggleModal()
{
    this.showModal = !this.showModal;
}
```